# How to Lock cell at selected Last Row?

Tags: excel, vba

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim lastRow As Long

lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row

ActiveSheet.Unprotect
lastRow.Locked = True
ActiveSheet.Protect

End Sub
```

*I already run this code. But still not lock the last row.
*When add "MsgBox lastrow" its working and show correct selected row.
*Thank You

Open This For More Info ----> [Excel View With Msg Box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPDLo.png)

Comment: change your line `lastRow.Locked = True`  to `Cells(lastRow, "E").Locked = True` if you want to unlock the last cell in Column E

Comment: If you want to lock the entire last row, the use `Cells(lastRow, "E").EntireRow.Locked = True`

Comment: Still got debug for "Cells(lastRow, "E")Locked = True" http://imgur.com/89tyuR3

Comment: I only now looked at your sheet structure, you are using merged cells for Columns  E:K, is there a reason you are merging them ?

Comment: try my code in the answer below, and see if it works for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case your cell in Column E is part of a merged cells (in your case Columns E:K are merged), then you set a new `Range` with the variable `MergedCell` to the merged area, and then `Lock` the entire range of merged cells.

### Code

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim lastRow As Long, cell As Range, MergedCell As Range

' find last row in Column E
lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row

ActiveSheet.Unprotect

Set cell = Range("E" & lastRow)

' if cell in Column E is part of merged cells
If cell.MergeCells = True Then
    Set MergedCell = cell.MergeArea
    MergedCell.Locked = True
Else
    cell.Locked = True
End If

ActiveSheet.Protect

End Sub
```

Comment: @Falhuddin you're welcome, please mark as answer (press the little **V**)